# Script (vba) to create a rule in Outlook to defer delivery of a message

Tags: vba, outlook, rules

I need to create a rule in Outlook to defer delivery of a message

The code is like this:

```
Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
'Create the rule by adding a SendRule to Rules collection
Set oRule = colRules.Create("Envoi différé", olRuleSend)
Set oDeferRuleAction = oRule.Actions(OlRuleActionType.olRuleActionDefer)
With oDeferRuleAction
  .Enabled = True

' then the first action is activate "delete category" but not defer delivery 
' and I can't set a number of minutes

End With
```

Something is missing and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: any final solution about it?

Answer (score 0):

See  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868996(v=office.14).aspx

olRuleActionDefer

Supported when creating new rules programmatically?: No